# How do you crop and scale with "auto" gravity using Cloudflare image URLs?

Tags: cloudflare

Using the [Cloudflare edge platform](https://developers.cloudflare.com/images/image-resizing/url-format/), I'm trying to compose an image URL to both crop *and* scale with automatic gravity, i.e. focal point.

I know the motif of the original 1600x800 image fits within 800x800 pixels, but I don't know *where* the center of the motif is.

I therefore want to apply automatic gravity, to have Cloudflare determine an appropriate focal point around which to crop the image.

**Once the image is cropped, I want to display it with a size of 400x400 pixels.**

This hopefully illustrates what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

However, I cannot seem to combine this into a single URL.

I tried doing something like the following, which indeed does crop *and* scale, but it always crops from the left, regardless of `gravity` parameter:

`https://mysite.uri/cdn-cgi/image/fit=crop,gravity=auto,trim.width=800,trim.height=800,width=400/image.jpg`

I can successfully crop with automatic gravity. For example, this produces an 800x800 square image, automatically cropped towards the main motif of the image:

`https://mysite.uri/cdn-cgi/image/fit=crop,gravity=auto,width=800,height=800/image.jpg`

However, I want to *render* this image as 400x400 pixels, without cropping any more of the original image.

Comment: The following suggests I might not have the level of control over the size of the crop area (how much of the original image is included) before scaling: https://community.cloudflare.com/t/compose-image-url-to-crop-and-scale-with-automatic-gravity/565563/5